# How to have a horizontal filling areaplot in R

Tags: r, plot

Imagine a normal area plot of a continuous function y = f(x), which fills the area below the plotted graph down to the x-axis.

But I have to plot my data transposed. The y-data is now on the horizontal axis and the x-data is now on the vertical axis. I want to have the very same plot as before, just transposed ... so the filling should go left, towards the vertical y-axis.

But I can't find a fitting argument for this in the [R documentation of areaplot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/areaplot/versions/1.2-0/topics/areaplot)

Can you help me? Is there a work around?

Comment: Have you tried using ggplot2?

Comment: I am not familiar with ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the axes just by switching where you use x and y.  You can fill the area "under" the curve using `polygon`.   Here is a simple example with the Gaussian distribution.

```
## Data
x = seq(-3.5,3.5,0.1)
y = dnorm(y)

## Plot
plot(y, x, type="l", xaxs="i", xlim=c(0,0.45))
polygon(y,x, col="gray")
```

[image: Sideways plot]